# Object array argument isn't being understood by FullCalendar object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fullcalendar

I'm populating an object array from an ajax call using jQuery, in order to display event data from our system into the calendar. For some reason, it won't recognize it as events, and they aren't being displayed on the calendar. See code below.

I've checked it over 100 times, and I'm sure the data is coming in the correct format. The `events` variable is also not empty at runtime.

```
var events = [];

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "ajax/shared.ashx",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'm=get-staff-schedule',
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json);
            $.each(json.response.data, function (i, app) {
                events.push({
                    id: app.id,
                    title: app.ADMIN_NAME,
                    daysOfWeek: app.day - 1,
                    startTime: app.time_in,
                    endTime: app.time_out
                });

            });
            renderCalendar(events);
        }
    });

function renderCalendar(events) {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var d = new Date();
        var date = d.getFullYear() + '-' + padDigits(d.getMonth() + 1, 2) + '-' + padDigits(d.getDate(), 2)
        debugger
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'bootstrap'],
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
            defaultDate: date,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            events: events
        });

        calendar.render();
    }
```

Here is the image of the rendered, blank, calendar. Also, here are FullCalendar's docs for reference: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing

[image: emptycal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Only took me like 2 hours!

Basically, this object requires all strings. So, the `daysOfWeek` value needed to be converted from an integer to a string. Here is what I did:

```
events.push({
   id: app.id,
   title: app.ADMIN_NAME,
   daysOfWeek: (app.day - 1) + '',
   startTime: app.time_in,
   endTime: app.time_out
});
```

Comment: daysOfWeek is meant to be an array, technically. The event parsing article you linked to does mention it clearly. You might get away with supplying a string if you only want to select one day, maybe fullCalendar can still parse that, but it's not what's documented

Comment: oh you are correct! interesting, it indeed works with just a string of a single integer :D

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
events.push({
                    id: app.id,
                    title: app.ADMIN_NAME,
                    daysOfWeek: app.day - 1,
                    startTime: app.time_in,
                    endTime: app.time_out
                });
```

by

```
events.push({
                    id: app.id,
                    title: app.ADMIN_NAME,
                    daysOfWeek: app.day - 1,
                    start: app.time_in,
                    end: app.time_out
                });
```

Comment: It still does not work. Not only that, but it is wrong. If you read the documentation, you would see how they explain to use `startTime` and `endTime` for recurring events. `start` and `end` are for fixed events.